# How to modify html tag href link with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, google-tag-manager, buttonclick

I don't have access to the original document... so I am trying to modify a button element using GTM and Jquery.

But the follwing code is not working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".label" ).html("<a href="#" name="button" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'Form Sent'});"><strong>SiGN IN!</strong></a>")
});
</script>
```

Is there another way to accomplish this ?

Comment: That's invalid code, you're using the same quotes inside the string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something more complex since you have nested quotes:

```js
$(function(){
  let $newLink = $("<a/>",{ "href": "#", "name":"button" })
    .html('<strong>SiGN IN!</strong>'); // using separate .html instead of attribute for readability 
  $newLink.on("click",function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
   dataLayer.push({'event': 'Form Sent'}) 
  });
  $(".label" ).html($newLink)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label"></div>
```